# SQL Query replace duplicates with NULL or empty string ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am using oracle SQL
and have table with duplicate rows like this one:

```
Month   Product

March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
```

I need to transform it to something like this:

```
Month   Product

March   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April   ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
        ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
```

I am trying to use `SELECT (case when row_number() over (partition by times.calendar_month_name order by (select NULL)) = 1 then times.calendar_month_name end) Month` but not working... Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` window function:

```
select 
  nullif(Month, lag(Month) over (order by null)) Month,
  Product
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00c8fdd59a194417baba2c206ed6361a).
Results:

```
> MONTH | PRODUCT                       
> :---- | :-----------------------------
> March | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
> April | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
>       | ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
```

Comment: Is there a way to replace null with blank?

Comment: For Oracel `null` and `''` is the same, so if you replace `null`s with `''` you will get `null`s. What you can do is replace `null`s with `' '` (a space).

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=194fc2120aa4002eaecc0428530fdb1a

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> break on month
SQL>
SQL> select month, product from test order by month desc;

MONTH      PRODUCT
---------- ------------------------------
March      ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
April      ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)
           ENVOY & External Keyboard (22)

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation is really better done at the application level.  You can use `row_number()`, but you need to be careful:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1 then month end) as month, product
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by month order by month) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by month, seqnum;
```

Note that a SQL query returns results in an *indeterminate* order.  So you need an outer `order by` to guarantee the ordering (i.e. that the "first" row has the value).  Because you are dealing with exact duplicates, there is no unique sort key, so even two calls to `row_number()` could produce different results -- hence the use of a subquery.